# too many file open error multipeprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am parsing data from 100K files and saving these data into another file for further process. 
I implement the multiprocessing module in python for accelerating the process.

```
processes = []
for num in range(1, 5000):
    string = "{0:06}".format(num)
    path = "filename"+num+".npy"
    check_file_exist = Path(path)
    if check_file_exist.is_file():
        ## Multiprocessing for generating file using multiple cpus
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Get_feature_vector, args=(path,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    else:
        print("file not found", string)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Above code creates error `[Errno 24] Too many open files`. 
For solving this error, how do I take to make multiprocessing to open only 20-30 files at a time to process?

I used to read the documentation on `pool.map()` but create a list of 100K file names is out of my expectation. Do we have any efficient acceleration methods without opening a large number of files? I have a computer which has 40 processors.

Comment: "but I dont want to create list of 100K file names" Why not? You already do that by spawning parallel processes, it's just hidden. Yes, pool and a list/queue of tasks is the right way to do it.

Comment: will it not have effect on performance and memory if I save 100K files path in list.

Comment: It will affect memory, sure. Let's say that on average your file path takes 100 bytes (unlikely for paths to be so big). Then 100k*100=10mln. Meaning you use ~10Mb of RAM. How does it matter? Do you live in 90's? Also note that spawning 100k processes uses waaaay more memory, especially since each one has to have a file path inside as well.

Comment: Another way is to spawn say 40 processes and let them generate those filenames by incrementing [locked, shared value variable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value). This requires more work though.

Comment: I am new to this multiprocessing not sure how to use locked thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to generate the whole list, use the handy generator, that will yield a specified number of files, that you feed to the `pool.map()`:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(list(chunks(range(10, 75), 10)))
[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
 [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
 [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
 [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
 [70, 71, 72, 73, 74]]
```

Or in your case you may use:

```
for chunk in chunks(range(1, 5000), 10):  # chunk size is the same as pool size = 10
    file_names = []
    for num in chunk :
        string = "{0:06}".format(num)
        path = "filename"+num+".npy"
        check_file_exist = Path(path)
        file_names.append( path )

Pool(10).map( Get_feature_vector, file_names ) # etc.
```